# Tomcat for development and testing and Websphere for production

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere

does anybody have any experiences to share regarding developing Java Web Applications including Web Services Apps (no EJBs) to run on IBM Websphere using as development/testing platform eclipse with tomcat (or some other servlet container) ? For instance, any caveats regarding the xml configuration file differences between platforms ?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would suggest you use Tomcat for local development and then WAS in an integration environment so you can catch any problems before they go into production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of differences in the configuration along with how the runtime interprets java.   With Tomcat, you won't be able to see the behaviors of WAS and would only see them once you get into production.  In fact, IBM wrote a 400+ page of some of the migration issues you might face (http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246690.html). I would highly, highly suggest that you use RAD for WebSphere Application Server development.